# Index Values Do Not Equal Answers

Tags: javascript

I am creating a hangman game and need the green rectangles to change to red rectangles when the inputted answer by the player is INCORRECT. The total calculating function works, the input !==answers does not work which is what I need help with.

```
var total = 0;

gameboard.fillStyle = 'green';
gameboard.fillRect(10, 30, 30, 30)
gameboard.fillRect(80, 30, 30, 30)
gameboard.fillRect(150, 30, 30, 30)


$('#total_score').on('click', calculate);

function calculate() {
    for (var index = 0; index < 14; index = index + 1) {
        if ($('#' + index).val() == answers[index]) {
            total = total + 1;
        }
        if ($('#' + index).val() !== answers[index]) {
            gameboard.fillStyle = 'red';
            gameboard.fillRect(10, 30, 30, 30)
        }
    }
    $('#display_total').html(total);
    total = 0;
};
```

Comment: I've made your code readable ... it's like you stopped indenting after one level!!

Comment: when you say "it does not work", what should it do, what does it actually do?

Comment: adding some `HTML` markup, to make it a code snippet, would help to see if these numerical selectors even select something... find this rather uncommon, if that's not even invalid.

Comment: Please, read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and edit your question, according to the community standarts

Comment: Insert HTML codes